# How to use multiple implements in laravel model

Tags: php, laravel

How can I have multiple implements in my model?

my current model is like this:

```
class Post extends Model implements ViewableContract
{
........
}
```

now i need to add `implements Feedable` as well.

**should i use comma in between or put them in brackets or what?**

Comment: Yeah you can use **comma** in between the ViewableContract and Feedable like this:  `class Post extends Model implements ViewableContract, Feedable`

Comment: If it working can I post this as answer for other user help

Comment: @InzamamIdrees sure go ahead

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yeah! you can use **comma** in between the ViewableContract and Feedable like this:

```
class Post extends Model implements ViewableContract, Feedable
{
.....
}
```