# How to use more than 3 implements in laravel model (Laravel Excel)

Tags: php, laravel

When I set 3 implementations like below, there was an error: `Class App\Exports\JobsExport contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting::columnFormats)`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Job;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;

class JobsExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithColumnFormatting
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function collection()
    {
        $downloadColumns = Job::select(
            "id",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
            "deleted_at",
        )->get();

        return $downloadColumns;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return config("job.csv_header");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set more than 3?

**Related question**
[How to use multiple implements in laravel model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662121/how-to-use-multiple-implements-in-laravel-model)

Answer (score 1):

Your class could be implementing any number of interfaces. There's no limit on that.

All you need to do for the program to work properly is just to implement all the methods declared in all the interfaces your class implements.

The error you're getting means you just have one method missing in your class.

By the way, the code you provided is not the class that causes the error.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I put wrong example and edited it.

As u mentioned the issue happened because I didn't add columnFormat method which is provided in WithColumnFormatting interface.

Now I solved it and found I could add more than 3 interfaces, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

AS I put a comment, the cause is quite simple.
I didn't add a method which is provided by WithColumnFormatting interface.

Now I found I could add more than 3 interfaces now, thank you so much for answer&comment.